# Access JS Function in Global Scope

Tags: javascript

I have defined a variable within a function that is found in the global scope. I can access my function `foo()` by going `window.foo`. I am wondering how would I be able to modify the contents of `data` within `foo()`? I have tried going `window.foo.data` but i receieve the message `undefined`.

```
<script>
    function foo() {
        data =  {
            one : '1',
            two : '2'
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling foo()?

Comment: I cannot modify the existing JS code, so data must exist within `foo()`. I am calling `foo()` from the console.

Comment: Anything "inside" the function only exists during its execution. Some *data* can exist after the function terminated, if it was made accessible outside. `window.foo.data` would try to access the **property** `data` on the function *object* `foo`. However, the function does not have such a property. When the function is *executed* it will try to access the (free) variable `data`. A *variable* is not a *property*, nor does anything *inside* the function relate to the function *object* (unless you use recursion I guess (and ignoring the fact that the body is of course an internal property)).

Comment: window.foo() and then access with window.data. data becomes a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example, all you need to do is *call* `foo()` which will set the global variable `data`.  After that point, you can access it simply with `data`:

```js
function foo() {
   data =  {
      one : '1',
      two : '2'
   }
}

// At this point here, data does not exist since foo() has not been run

foo(); // Will run foo() and set the global variable data
window.alert(data.one);
```

With that said, I advise you to rework your code.  It's strongly inadvisable to *pollute* the global scope with random variables.  Instead, you should *declare* the variable `data` within a scope common to where you want to use it.  If, indeed, `data` must be accessible from anywhere, you should probably create a namespace for it.

This could be an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably come up with a better solution.

Comment: Sorry, I had a silly typo. Thank you Mike, this was the solution I am looking for! I agree that `foo()` needs to be re-worked, but that code belongs to someone else.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the contents of `data` without having to run `foo()`?

Comment: There *is no* `data` before `foo()` is run.  Thus, it has no contents to modify.  You're certainly welcome to set `data` to something else before running `foo`.  Running `foo` would then overwrite whatever previous value `data` had.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. This makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating `data` as though it's an attribute of `foo`. However, it's actually a global variable. Until you execute `foo`, `data` doesn't exist. *After* you execute `foo()`, `data` is a global value completely unconnected to `foo`.

Comment: Since the variable isn't declared with `var`, it's not *local*.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for catching that; embarrassing. Fixed. I'd upvote the comment twice if I could.